# Java RESTful WebService Maven dependency error

Tags: java, rest, web-services

Recently I am learning RESTful web service with Java and I created a really simple example and trying things out and I am having some problems understanding some behavior of this kind of implementation.I have a class called WebServiceServer which is the following:

```
package example.restful.server;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import example.restful.entity.Employee;

@Path("employee")
public class WebServiceServer {

    @GET
    @Path("id/{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(id);
        employee.setState("NY");
        employee.setName("Tom");
        return employee;
    }
}
```

and an entity class called Employee:

```
package example.restful.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement()
public class Employee {
private String id;
private String name;
private String state;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
```

below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"             
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"         
version="3.1">
  <display-name>WebServiceRestful01</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Webapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-
class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>example</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Webapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and below are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

when I run this example on tomcat server and type the following url I get this result:
[image]

but, now I add the org.glassfish.jersey.core jersey-client to my maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and retry again I get an error:
[image]

I did not change a single line of code but upon adding this dependency I get an this error and it turns out I have to add another dependency which is org.apache.cxf to fix the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

My question is: what effect did adding org.glassfish.jersey.core jersey-client to my example project do that caused the original function to not work anymore and why did adding org.apache.cxf fix the problem?

Comment: Did you `import` anything new upon adding this dependency?

Comment: I did not touch my code at all nor did I import anything new, all I did was add  the org.glassfish.jersey.core dependency to pom.xml, and retry again, but it occurred an exception, then I added another dependency org.apache.cxf and it worked again, trying to figure out what these dependencies did behind the scenes.

Comment: Adding dependencies can't change how your code runs, especially if you don't even import this package (and obviously you don't use it). You must be doing something else wrong. Maybe the server wasn't stopped before or the listening port is still open?

Comment: I stopped the server the proper way and restarted, and there is no difference, I think I need to look up on more information on this, and if you are curious too you can try this out too, this example only has 2 classes and some simple configurations which I have pasted above.

Comment: Your jersey client dependency is from the 2.x line, yet the server dependencies are from the 1.x line.  Is this on purpose?  You shouldn't need to bring in CXF to get Jersey to work; they're two independent JAX-RS impls.